# Rails: Unknown column in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to verify user login on a Rails app. The controller code looks like:

```
def create
  user = User.where(params[:session][:email]).first
  # user = User.where(:type=> 'User', :email => params[:session][:email])
  debugger
  if user and user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to admin_url
  else
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Invalid user/password combination"
  end
end
```

Parameters are being correctly passed, but it's trying to search for a 'users' attribute in the users table. There isn't a users attr. The `users` table looks like this:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE users;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userid     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fname      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lname      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you please show the generated SQL for the "broken" query?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, ActiveRecord generates a query where `params[:session][:email]` is a column name:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`<the value of params[:session][:email]>`)
```

You should provide column name in `where`:

```
user = User.where(email: params[:session][:email]).first
```

Or just use `find_by` instead of `where` + `first`:

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email])
```

Answer (score -1):

well there is a probleme in this line

```
user = User.where(params[:session][:email]).first
```

you want to search a user by his email address so you have to specify that (tell active record that I want to search for that specific field) like this

```
user = User.where(email: params[:session][:email]).first
```

Comment: why there is a downvote on my answer ?? am i wrong ??